# FATAL: Couldn't find any executable in D:\JenkinsSlave\tools\Maven_2.2.1

Tags: maven, jenkins

Building remotely on dswinbld301-Flex-Win

> FATAL: Couldn't find any executable in
>   D:\JenkinsSlave\tools\Maven_2.2.1

Comment: Stop Using [Maven 2.2.1 cause it's End Of Life](http://maven.apache.org/maven-2.x-eol.html). Start with Maven 3.X ...

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a path to an existing `maven` executable in the `MAVEN_HOME` field under Manage Jenkins ==> Configure System. Double check your configuration and make sure it is properly set up.

**Update:** In Jenkins 2.0, the maven configuration has moved. It is under Manage Jenkins ==> Global Tool Configuration ==> Maven. In the `MAVEN_HOME` field you should have something like: `/usr/share/maven3`.